# Дуговая диаграмма в Python или R

Tags: python, r, визуализация

Есть два поля таблицы, в каждой из которых по несколько категорий. 
Хотелось бы построить дуговую диаграмму или взвешенный граф, которые бы показывали частоту связей каждой категории одного поля с каждой категории другого. Гуглёж не дал внятного ответа, какие библиотеки для этого используются.

Подскажите, пакет для R или для Python, если несложно, то и с методом.

Comment: https://eax.me/python-matplotlib/??

Comment: Там о дуговых диаграммах нет ничего, смотрел уже

Comment: отрисуйте напрямую, в matplotlib всё есть для этого

Comment: Да, высокоуровневых решений даже в plotly нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например, можно использовать пакет [`arcdiagram`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arcdiagram).

если в вашей версии `r` он доступен, то сможете установить командой

```
install.packages('arcdiagram')
```

если, как в моей, недоступен, то можно скомпилировать его из исходников:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('gastonstat/arcdiagram')
```

---

приведённый в описании пакета демонстрационный скрипт рисует последовательно четыре графика (каждый — ещё и с анимацией):

```
library(igraph) # for graph.star
library(arcdiagram)

# create a star graph with 10 nodes
star_graph = graph.star(10, mode="out")

# extract edgelist
star_edges = get.edgelist(star_graph)

# inspect star_edges
star_edges

# plot 1: default arc diagram
arcplot(star_edges)

# plot 2: show nodes as circles, in decreasing order
arcplot(star_edges, show.nodes=TRUE, sorted=TRUE, decreasing=TRUE, las=1)

# plot 3: different ordering, arc widths, arc colors, and node sizes
set.seed(120)
arcplot(star_edges, ordering=sample(1:10), labels=paste("node",1:10,sep="-"),
   lwd.arcs=4*runif(10,.5,2), col.arcs=hsv(runif(9,0.6,0.8),alpha=0.4),
   show.nodes=TRUE, pch.nodes=21, cex.nodes=runif(10,1,3), 
   col.nodes="gray80", bg.nodes="gray90", lwd.nodes=2)

# plot 4: same as plot 3 but vertically oriented
set.seed(120)
op = par(mar = c(0.5, 5, 0.5, 3))
arcplot(star_edges, ordering=sample(1:10), horizontal=FALSE,
   labels=paste("node",1:10,sep="-"),
   lwd.arcs=4*runif(10,.5,2), col.arcs=hsv(runif(9,0.6,0.8),alpha=0.4),
   show.nodes=TRUE, pch.nodes=21, cex.nodes=runif(10,1,3), 
   col.nodes="gray80", bg.nodes="gray90", lwd.nodes=2)
par(op)
```

первая из анимаций:

```
arcplot(star_edges)
```

заканчивается такой картинкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

заканчивается всё «представление» вот такой картинкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]